# Make Properties readonly in addContentItemPropertiesPane

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-content-navigator, ibm-case-manager

I am looking for a modified add document view using **AddContentItemDialog** .

i manage to set parent folder , Intro Text , title and documents properties with script adapter in Work Details

```
    try {
         var parentFolder = self.case.getCaseFolder();
         self.addContentItemDialog = new AddContentItemDialog();

         self.addContentItemDialog.setDefaultContentClass(prefix+"_Dumy01");


         aspect.after(self.addContentItemDialog.addContentItemPropertiesPane, "onCompleteRendering", function() {

             console.log("aspect.after(self.addContentItemDialog");

              self.addContentItemDialog.addContentItemPropertiesPane.setPropertyValue("Test_1", "123");
              self.addContentItemDialog.addContentItemPropertiesPane.setPropertyValue("DocumentTitle", "YYYYYY");

              self.addContentItemDialog.set("title","This is New Add Doc Event");
              self.addContentItemDialog.setIntroText("New Msg Can Be Set In this Tab");
         }, true);
         console.log("XX");
         self.addContentItemDialog.show(parentFolder.repository,parentFolder,true,false, null, null, false, null);
}catch (exception) {                                   
     console.log("exception" + exception);
}
```

Now I am looking to make few Properties readonly after setting them up from script.

maybe like ,

```
self.addContentItemDialog.addContentItemPropertiesPane(Property).set("readOnly", "true");
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at  below two methods. this might help
afterRenderAttributes(attributeDefinitions, item, reason, isReadOnly)
  
beforeRenderAttributes(attributeDefinitions, item, reason, isReadOnly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix for this was , to call this under "*onCompleteRendering*"

```
        var fields = this._commonProperties._propertyEditors._fields;

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

          if(_logic_){  //Like (fields[i].get('name') == (prefix+"_MainFileCategory"));
            fields[i].readOnly = true;
            fields[i].textbox.readOnly = true;
          }
        }
```

found idea from http://www.notonlyanecmplace.com .

Comment: @Amessihel , http://www.notonlyanecmplace.com/about-me/  , pick the idea in comments for making required fields false .

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, I am led to believe that your best option in that case would be EDS, it would be easier and more flexible. please check the link below from ECM community blog, giving a simple example that you can leverage to achieve similar results

[Sample External Data Service for IBM Case Manager by Dave Hanson](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/e8206aad-10e2-4c49-b00c-fee572815374/entry/sample_external_data_service_for_ibm_case_manager_by_dave_hanson6?lang=en)

Also, Please check the ICM 5.2 Redbook, which referenced Chapter 16 of the previous edition of the ICM Redbook (the ICM 5.1 edition): [Download](ftp://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247929/SG24792902.PDF)

Finally, This link from developerWorks is a straight forward white paper with sample code that I found very useful back when I started using EDS for case manager: [Download](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/form/anonymous/api/library/a82c60c3-d3d9-4444-9f9f-63678cf12c17/document/8d064a0f-c716-4d55-85a4-9910dd43563f/media.)